# Can't install nginx using epel repo on Centos 7 (64bit)

Tags: centos, nginx

I've just built a 64 bit Centos server and I'm trying to install NGINX on it. Using the epel 7 (beta) repo I get the following error when trying to install:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.as29550.net
 * epel: mirror.vorboss.net
 * extras: centos.hyve.com
 * updates: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package nginx.x86_64 0:1.0.15-5.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1) for package: nginx-1.0.15-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: nginx-1.0.15-5.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: nginx-1.0.15-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libpcre.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: nginx-1.0.15-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.10.1)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Has anyone managed to install NGINX via yum successfully?

Comment: That's ancient. I'd rather use nginx's own yum repo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would propose adding the nginx repo

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/noarch/RPMS/nginx-release-centos-7-0.el7.ngx.noarch.rpm
```

That should  solve your problem.

Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

That doesn't seem right as the nginx version in in the EPEL repository for RHEL7 x86_64 is [1.6.1](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/repoview/nginx.html).

Try `yum clean all; yum update` and repeat the installation process. If it still fails, try to specify a different mirror (as the one you're using seems out of sync).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't install the EPEL 7 repository. That's the EPEL 6 repository. Remove it and try again.

Better yet, install nginx from [their own repositories](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable) to ensure that you stay up to date with critical and less critical upstream fixes.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me. I updated my EPEL repository with

`yum update epel-release`

and boom! I was able to install nginx with

`yum install nginx`